# Migration of Maven's "versions:use-latest-versions" to Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm migrating my pom.xml file from Maven to Gradle.
There's following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <allowMajorUpdates>false</allowMajorUpdates>
        <allowMinorUpdates>false</allowMinorUpdates>
        <allowIncrementalUpdates>false</allowIncrementalUpdates>
        <allowSnapshots>false</allowSnapshots>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So the above config updates dependencies, for example, from version "10.0.1-SNAPSHOT" to "10.0.1-86", so only the qualifier ("SNAPSHOT") is replaced with the latest build number (86).

It's not clear how to achieve this in Gradle. I found [gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin](https://github.com/patrikerdes/gradle-use-latest-versions-plugin), but I don't see settings for major/minor/incremental/build numbers. It updates to the latest possible version without restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not clear how to achieve this in Gradle.

Gradle does not offer such functionality out of the box. Instead you must rely on plugins to achieve this much like your current Maven configuration.

An alternative is approach, although not exactly what you're looking for is to declare a [version range](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html).

But as I said, you will need to find a plugin that matches your criteria, or write one yourself.